# How to plot degree assortativity using R?

Tags: r, igraph, sna, network-analysis

I am working on degree assortativity. I have calculated degree assortativity using R using igraph package.I tried this code but it only calculates overall degree assortativity value

```
[library(igraph)
datafile <- "c:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\data.csv"
sd_edgelist <- read.csv(datafile)
sd_edgelist <- sd_edgelist\[, 1:9 \]
head(sd_edgelist)
g <- graph.data.frame(sd_edgelist, directed = FALSE)
assortativity_degree(g, directed=FALSE)
    #\[1\] -0.6721889][1]
```

i  want to calculate every node assortativity value and then want to plot scatter plot like this how this can be done ? i didnt find any builtin function i R for calculating assortativity for every node 
After calculating assortativity value for every node i want scatter plot like this plot  [Open link to see image of scatter plot]

https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=degree%20assortativity%20plot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjnLyO7d_TAhUh6oMKHYwmBv4Q_AUICigB#imgrc=QWHV9xLoYCDnXM:

Comment: It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Clearly describe the desired output (what would the x and y axis be for your scatter plot). Describe how you exactly you want to calculate a per-node assortativity value.

Comment: we would iterate over nodes and for every node checked neighbourhood A, and similar node set B AUB/(A+B) ~ assortativity  .... we can fine-tune formula for assotrativity computation.... ~ stands for 'more or less close to'

Comment: on x-axis the degree and on y axis we have average degree of neighbours.. see attached scatter plot in the post

Comment: on x-axis the degree and on y axis we have average degree of neighbours.. see the link embeded in post for required scatter plot

Comment: for graph G with N nodes we need to have 1) degree for every node 2) degree assortativity for every node 3) plot these two 1-dimensional vectors of lenght N in lolglog scale (matplotlib has this function)